# Eliminate Nulls from Pivot Clause

Tags: null, pivot

Using the below code to pivot data. Any insight on how I can replace Nulls with '0' on the pivot output?

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR (MAX)
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), date, 120) + ']', 
      '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), date, 120) + ']')
       FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), date, 120) as date FROM #temp6) PV  
       ORDER BY date

SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT ID, [Property Name], [Fund], value, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), date, 120) as date FROM #temp6
) AS t
PIVOT 
(
  sum(value) 
  FOR date IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
') AS p ;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Which variety of SQL are you using? If it's T-SQL you can use ISNULL(column, 0) to convert nulls to 0 in the select.

Comment: SQL Server Express